# express 4 jade invalid error

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am using express 4 with jade. I have an error in the jade template like this:

file: test.jade,  data.item.test is undefined:

```
extends layout

block content
if data.item.test
    div.content-section
```

the  html response looks like this:

```
TypeError: /work/web/views/layout.jade:37
   35|                 header
   36|                   i.arrow-up
 > 37|                   h4.user-name #{user.firstName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + user.firstName.slice(1)} #{user.lastName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + user.lastName.slice(1)}
   38|                   a(href="/profile").edit-profile
   39|                     i
   40|                     | Edit Profile

Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined
```

if I fix the actual error in the jade template, everything will work fine and no error will be reported in the layout.

How can I fix this because it's very difficult to debug errors in jade templates

Comment: Your user is undefined so you need to define it. Can't suggest more than that as you haven't shown where user gets passed in.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the problem was in the error template. It was using the same layout as the other pages and the user is required there but is not sent from the error handler.